# APNS Push not received

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, apns-php

I am trying to implement push notification in apple, and when i send the push it is sent locally from my machine, but when i send it from a server it is not received on the device. What could be the issue ?

Comment: If it works when pushing from your local machine, the problem is probably port 2195 being blocked in your server's network. The only other reason I can think of is that your code doesn't find (or have access to) the key-store file when deployed on your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

port was not opened my server this is the problem i asked them to open the port and it worked